# Cannot install bomi (CMPlayer) on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: kubuntu, dependencies, ffmpeg, bomi

I was a fan of [bomi](https://bomi-player.github.io/) player on ubuntu, but cannot install it on the latest version, anybody got a solution?

```
usr@host: ~$ sudo apt-get install bomi
[sudo] password for usr: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
bomi : Depends: libavcodec-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thx guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Still doesn't work with the long PPA answer :-( but thx, trying to compile the source version but messing with dependancies :S

Comment: you can try out to use synaptic package manager in order to install new packages and view dependencies etc. in a nice GUI. You can install it using `sudo apt-get install synaptic` I use it often to fix dependency problems. Maybe it will help you to find out what is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

Bomi is working on Ubuntu 18.04 - 21.10

[image]

Is here : [https://launchpad.net/~nemonein/+archive/ubuntu/bomi](https://launchpad.net/%7Enemonein/+archive/ubuntu/bomi)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemonein/bomi
sudo apt get update
sudo apt install bomi
```

Only exist Focal/Bionic and Cosmic.
I using Focal bionic repo, on my Ubuntu 21.10.